# Have got or have?

Tags: tense

I know how does it work when we are talking about past simple and present perfect, but how it works with present simple vs present perfect ?

Like have got or have ?

for example:
   I have got a car or I have a car ?

is there any difference ?

I found that have got is less formal than have

Comment: Could you please give a fuller example of the usage you are unsure about, and how it confuses you, or what you are unsure about?

Answer (score 2):

"I have got a car" could mean the same as "I have a car" but less formal (as you said).

BUT

It could also mean that you have received a car (but someone would generally say "I have gotten a car"). The verb *to get* has lots of definitions and is VERY commonly used for different things.

You can even say "I got a car" (as in "I have a car") which is MUCH less formal, but it can also mean you received a car like the past-particle of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Using "have" in a sentence is normal usage as well as correct grammar. Using "have got", while it may be often heard to be used, is poor grammar.

People do say, "I have got a car", but this is poor grammar. Correct grammar is, "I have a car."

The verb *get* has the form "get/got/gotten" as described [here](https://web.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/get-got.htm):

> get/got/gotten
>
> *Get* is the present tense form of the verb. *Got* is the past tense form as well as one of the two alternatives for the past participle. The other alternative for the past participle is *gotten*, which is generally preferred in the United States.
>
> We **get** our raw materials from companies in Texas and Nevada.
>   We **got** our raw materials from companies in Texas and Nevada.
>
> We have always **gotten** our chemicals from companies in Texas and Nevada.
>
> In informal contexts, many speakers use *have got*, *'ve got*, or simply *got* to mean "have" or "must." You should avoid this usage of the verb get in your writing; instead, use *have* or *must*.
>
> Weak
>   We **have got** several problems on our hands.
>
> Improved
>   We **have** several problems on our hands.
>
> Unacceptable
>   We **got** several problems on our hands.
>
> Acceptable
>   We **have** several problems on our hands.
>
> Weak
>   **We've got** to find a solution to our problems.
>
> Improved
>   We **must** find a solution to our problems.