# Meanings of Have and Get

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Get = Gain possession of something

Have = To possess something

Can Get mean Have sometimes?
"I can't go the cinema, I got/have got no money at all."

I see sentences like this a lot and I wonder about it.

Comment: This is covered [in other questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217574/have-got-or-have), but to be honest the answers there are not very good. One answer there simply dismisses "got" as "poor grammar," but [this Cambridge Dictionary page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have) is more on track by saying it's "more informal," and explaining more.

Comment: @AndyBonner We also discussed this issue recently at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309358/i-have-got-to-sing-or-i-have-gotten-to-sing/309361 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303060/i-had-got-to-eat-burger. I'm not close-voting, but I'm not sure whether this question really adds anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In informal speech, it is common for English speakers in the U.S. to say "I've got something" (or "no something") in the sense of having a condition (like an illness) or living situation (like a job).

Less common is to say (for have) "I got" without "have" -- it sounds less educated and more like slang or dialect to say "I got no money" than to say "I've got no money" -- though it is common in some idiomatic speech.

In the sense of acquire or gain, "got" is common and grammatical: "I got a job offer yesterday" and "I got accepted at the university."

Comment: In British English _I've got_ meaning _I have_ is if anything even more common, and is used for physical objects, and in questions and negations ("Have you got the book?" "No, I haven't got any books.") But _I got_ without the _have_ or _'ve'_ is I think less common than in US English.

Comment: @user8356 I would like to know some examples of this idiomatic speech where "got" without "have" is common.

Comment: How about [this song?](https://genius.com/George-gershwin-i-got-plenty-o-nuttin-lyrics)